# How can I hide one div before opening another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make it so that only one div can be shown at a time? I've tried adding "document.getElementById(currentID).style.display='none';" in the after the else but that doesn't work.

```
<h5 onclick="showImage('chair')">Chair</h5>
<h5 onclick="showImage('table')">Table</h5>
<h5 onclick="showImage('long_table')">Meeting Table</h5>

<div id="chair">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" height="300px"/>
    <h4>Product 1</h4>
</div>

<div id="table">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" height="300px"/>
    <h4>Product 2</h4>
</div>

<div id="longtable">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" height="300px"/>
    <h4>Product 3</h4>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var currentID = "";
        function showImage(id){
            if(currentID == id){
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
                currentID = "";
            }else{
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
                currentID = id;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your elements don't actually have an ID, you should one to make your code work

Comment: They are changing other divs with ID's

Comment: "They are changing other divs with ID's" . Can include `html` of "other divs" ?

Comment: @JFK I need it so at the start there is no image showing, If i click a link such as 'Chair', the div with id of chair will be be showing. If I click 'Table', then chair div would hide and table div would be shown. But if I clicked 'Table' when table is already shown, it would just hide it.

Comment: I didn't answer but this is what I understood http://jsfiddle.net/19dz0x94/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to add a class to your HTML and then grab the divs by their class. You can then loop through the elements to hide them all and then un-hide the one you've clicked.

Example:

```js
var arrProducts = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
for (i = 0; i < arrProducts.length; i++) {
  arrProducts[i].style.display = 'none';
}

function showImage(id) {
  for (i = 0; i < arrProducts.length; i++) {
    if (id == arrProducts[i].id) {
      if (document.getElementById(id).style.display === 'none') {
        arrProducts[i].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        arrProducts[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    } else {
      arrProducts[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

}
```

```css
h5 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.product img {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h5 onclick="showImage('chair');">Chair</h5>
<h5 onclick="showImage('table');">Table</h5>
<h5 onclick="showImage('long_table');">Meeting Table</h5>

<div class="product" id="chair">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" height="300px" />
  <h4>Product 1 (Chair)</h4>
</div>

<div class="product" id="table">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" height="300px" />
  <h4>Product 2 (Table)</h4>
</div>

<div class="product" id="long_table">
  <img src="images/3.jpg" height="300px" />
  <h4>Product 3 (Meeting Table)</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tom I've updated it based upon the extra information you added in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink the logic of your function, I'm guessing this is what you meant:

```
    var currentID = "";
    function showImage(id){
        if(currentID != id){
            if (currentID != "") // added this test in response to JFK's comment
                document.getElementById(currentID).style.display='none';
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
            currentID = id;
        }
        else { // added after OP clarified the question
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
            currentID = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work because `currentID` is `null` on the first `click` ... then never matches

Comment: Just fix your typo and you will be half way of the request (see OP comments and accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

While this won't help you fix things in you current code, you can actually do this without any JavaScript by abusing radiobuttons. This is quite common.

http://jsfiddle.net/mo7yppp8/

Each div needs a radio button above it, and to be enclosed within a label. This way, clicking on the div will trigger the radiobutton, deselecting any other div in the process.

```
<label>
    <input class="divSelector" type="radio" name="divSelector" value="" />
    <div>Sample text</div>
</label>
```

Then, all you need is some CSS to hide the radiobuttons, and some to shrink the divs which aren't right after a checked input.

```
.divSelector {
    display: none;
}

.divSelector:checked + div {
    font-size: 12pt;
}

div {
    font-size: 0pt;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    overflow: clip;
    padding: 2em;
    height: 12px;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the chance to use jQuery, there is a really awesome solution possible. It would work like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnf6gsuL/2/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <h5>Chair</h5>
    <div>
        <img src="images/1.jpg" height="300px"/>
        <h4>Product 1</h4>
    </div>
    <h5>Table</h5>
    <div>
        <img src="images/2.jpg" height="300px"/>
        <h4>Product 2</h4>
    </div>
    <h5 id="longtable">Meeting Table</h5>
    <div>
        <img src="images/3.jpg" height="300px"/>
        <h4>Product 3</h4>
    </div>

<script>

    $("h5").click(function(eve){
        $("div").each(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut("fast", function(){
                $(eve.target).next("div").fadeIn("fast");
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `longtable` for `long_table` at "Meeting Table" `h5`

```js
var showImage = function showImage(id) {
  var active = document.getElementById(id);
  active.style.display = 'block';
  var notActive = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(#" + active.id + ")");
  Array.prototype.slice.call(notActive)
  .forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
  })

};
```

```css
div[id] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h5 onclick="showImage('chair')">Chair</h5>
<h5 onclick="showImage('table')">Table</h5>
<h5 onclick="showImage('longtable')">Meeting Table</h5>

<div id="chair">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" height="300px" alt="chair" />
  <h4>Product 1</h4>
</div>

<div id="table">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" height="300px" alt="table" />
  <h4>Product 2</h4>
</div>

<div id="longtable">
  <img src="images/3.jpg" height="300px" alt="meeting table" />
  <h4>Product 3</h4>
</div>
```